# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar una línea con sed cuando el valor de la línea coincida exactamente, sin más caracteres al final?

Tags: linux, regex, bash, csv, sed

Tengo una columna con nombres de variables que se repiten en un archivo csv

```
Ana
Maria
Maria 1
Ana
Maria 2
Juan
Ale
Maria
```

y tengo otro archivo con dos columnas en una está un nombre y en la otra un número por el que quiero reemplazarlo.

```
Ale > 1
Ana > 2
Juan > 3
Maria > 4
Maria 1 > 5
Maria 2 > 6
```

Quiero cambiar la línea completa que contenga un nombre por un número pero al usar `sed '/Maria/c 4' archivo.txt` se reemplazan también "Maria 1" y "Maria 2" y no quiero eso porque estos tienen número diferentes asignados.
¿Cómo puedo limitar el comando para que las expresiones que tienen añadidos más caracteres no sean afectados por el sed para obtener algo así?

```
2
4
5
2
6
3
1
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Indica que la palabra es *exactamente* lo que quieres sustituir:

```
sed '/^Maria$/c 4' fichero
```

Con `^` le indicas el principio de la línea y con `$` el final. Por tanto, solo encajará con las líneas que contengan exactamente "Maria", nada más.